# Video from channel not showing up with YouTube Data API

Tags: c#, .net, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

*According to [this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/support) I'm supposed to ask this question here*

I'm trying to get the most recent uploads for a channel (ExplosmEntertainment). I'm calling a `PlaylistItemsResource.ListRequest` (which has always worked) like this:

```
PlaylistItemsResource.ListRequest listRequest = service.PlaylistItems.List("snippet");
listRequest.PlaylistId = "UUWXCrItCF6ZgXrdozUS-Idw";
listRequest.MaxResults = 1;
PlaylistItemListResponse response = listRequest.Execute();
PlaylistItemSnippet newUploadDetails = response.Items.FirstOrDefault().Snippet;
```

The problem is that `newUploadDetails` lists this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PSHg-U4s-6c as the most recent upload whereas if you visit the actual [uploads playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=UUWXCrItCF6ZgXrdozUS-Idw), it is this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FHK4N8QLtBQ .

As this code has always worked for me thus far, this seems to be a problem with this video and the API, but is there something I'm doing wrong?

---

Edit:

This channel uploaded a new video last night (8/24/17) and I modified my code to this:

```
PlaylistItemsResource.ListRequest listRequest = service.PlaylistItems.List("snippet");
listRequest.PlaylistId = "UUWXCrItCF6ZgXrdozUS-Idw";
listRequest.MaxResults = 5;
PlaylistItemListResponse response = listRequest.Execute();
List<PlaylistItem> fiveRecent = response.Items.ToList();
```

@paolo suggested that maybe the results were getting cached and that's what I was seeing but in my `fiveRecent` list, the list is as follows:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SxYyTOgWBDI (published 8/24/2017 21:30:00)
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PSHg-U4s-6c (published 8/21/2017 22:00:00)
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e-cbR0JwgsA (published 8/13/2017 22:00:00)
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FHK4N8QLtBQ (published 8/23/2017 22:00:00)
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fczItbbB-OA (published 8/16/2017 22:00:01)

So these results show that the `response.Items` are not ordered by published date. And, unfortunately, [there doesn't seem to be](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) an `OrderBy` parameter like there is with some of the [other APIs and their list methods](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list).

**This is the same order that the API Explorer gives**

It is very odd to me that this order doesn't match the order in the [actual playlist on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=UUWXCrItCF6ZgXrdozUS-Idw). Does anyone have any suggestions for a different way to get the most recently uploaded video?

Comment: When performing this request with the [API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.playlistItems.list?part=snippet%252CcontentDetails&maxResults=1&playlistId=UUWXCrItCF6ZgXrdozUS-Idw&_h=3&), it seems to work fine. Is there maybe some kind of caching layer between your code and the API?

Comment: @paolo I have done more investigation and added some more found information. Please see my edit in the question

Answer (score 2):

> It is very odd to me that this order doesn't match the order in the actual playlist on YouTube

Same here. One would definitively expect that.

Ok, when I do this:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&fields=items/snippet/publishedAt%2Citems/snippet/position%2Citems/snippet/title&maxResults=5&playlistId=UUWXCrItCF6ZgXrdozUS-Idw&key=API_KEY HTTP/1.2
```

I get this:

```
{
 "items": [
  {
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2017-08-25T04:30:00.000Z",
    "title": "Ow, My Dick: The Aftermath - A Cyanide & Happiness True Story",
    "position": 0
   },
   "contentDetails": {
    "videoId": "SxYyTOgWBDI"
   }
  },
  {
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2017-08-22T05:00:00.000Z",
    "title": "X-Ray - Cyanide & Happiness Minis",
    "position": 1
   },
   "contentDetails": {
    "videoId": "PSHg-U4s-6c"
   }
  },
  {
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2017-08-14T05:00:00.000Z",
    "title": "Explosm Presents: Channelate - Drinkin' Alone",
    "position": 2
   },
   "contentDetails": {
    "videoId": "e-cbR0JwgsA"
   }
  },
  {
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2017-08-24T05:00:00.000Z",
    "title": "High Noon - Cyanide & Happiness Shorts",
    "position": 3
   },
   "contentDetails": {
    "videoId": "FHK4N8QLtBQ"
   }
  },
  {
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2017-08-17T05:00:01.000Z",
    "title": "Final Words - Cyanide & Happiness Shorts",
    "position": 4
   },
   "contentDetails": {
    "videoId": "fczItbbB-OA"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

The order and times are the same as you provided, just GMT instead of PDT. But this also shows that the items are ordered by `position` - which in theory should of course be analogue to `publishedAt`.

Since it's not, I suggest fetching the first few, say 10 or 15, items of the playlist and ordering these by date. Then pray that the actual latest video is among those first X positions. I really can't think of anything else here.

Comment: "Then pray that the actual latest video is among those first X positions"

Marvelous. I think the bigger problem is that somehow, on a channel's uploads playlist, position doesn't match published date (even though that is the very definition of that playlist)

Comment: Agreed. But unfortunately, we can't change that. If you don't want to pray, you could instead grab all playlist items and order by date, but that takes 1 request per 50 items and could become quite quota-intensive.

Comment: Exactly. Hopefully Google engineers will see this question eventually (like [this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/support) says they will)

Comment: You could go ahead and [file this as a bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=186600&template=874803). Maybe they'll see it in the bug tracker.

Comment: Thanks! I'll go ahead and do that

Comment: Done. Let's see what becomes of this: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65067744